# Python Hex String Check If Bit is set

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given a string consiting of a hex number.

```
s = "F716F92C8Aba"
```

What is the easiest way to determine if the `n`th bit counting from right is set to 1 or not? So `n=0` would be the most right bit.

Python 2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
if int(s, 16) & 2**n:
  whatever
```